# Applications of nanomechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, microscopy, applied-physics, nanoscience

What are applications of [nanomechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanomechanics) beyond its use in atomic force microscopy? The question is specifically about the existing applications rather than the potential/future ones (which are quite a few).

Answer (score 1):

For one they are used to measure properties (Youngs modulas and hardness) of different materials. Microspheres have myriad uses in modern life. Hollow microspheres are used to lower the density of manufactured materials. Nanoindentation is fundamental to the understanding of how materials perform at the nano- and micro-scale. Nanomechanics allows for researchers to gain a unique look at how their materials behave, allowing for an unparalleled understanding of their characteristics. So most of these are related to performance measurements, but this is the expertise of a single company.

These topics and others are described in this single reference given [here](http://nanomechanicsinc.com/nanomechanics-inc-applications/),

Comment: Indeed, this company comes among the first in Google. I however didn't pay much attention, since it seems like another startup or spin-off - they are doing their unique thing, whereas I am interested in commercial products or established technologies.

Answer (score 1):

It can be used to probe/understand nanoelectromechanical devices (NEMS). These are useful for weighing small molecules and other things.

They are also useful for probing microelectronics and measuring nanoscale strain which can affect the electrical properties of transistors.